# ForkjoinPool doesnt have a BlockingQueue

Tags: java, multithreading

Why does `ForkJoinPool` not have a `BlockingQueue` like `ThreadPoolExecutor`? It also doesn't seem to have a rejection queue.

I have been using `ThreadPoolExecutor` and blocking queues for both the above purposes are able to help asynchronous operations, which seems harder with `ForkJoinPool`. Any suggestions or comments will help.

Answer (score 1):

ForkJoinPool is special in which it doesnt have just one Queue.  It actually has as many queues as there are threads and the threads will execute off it's queue and when empty steal work from another thread's queue.

That being said, you shouldn't be given the option to override the queue considering its complexity.

Comment: So, you mean that there is no inbound queue to submit the outside task? If that is the case, then how (or who) is actually distributing the main tasks (not the sub tasks) to the individual thread queues?

Comment: Well the way you are supposed to do it is to submit initially to the pool.  Then each recursive task `fork()` and `join()` accordingly.  While doing that the FJP will take each task and distribute it to the threads as it sees fit.

Comment: The initial thread you submit on will eventually tell other threads when a task is available and they can go ahead and start scanning the queue the thread notifying.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. So, its something that FJP would do on its own.